# How do I hide the "App permission management is running" notification?

Tags: permissions

I have a vernee Apollo Lite which runs Android 6.0.

There's a permanent notification called "App permission management is runn..." The App name seems to be Permission Control.

It's always there and clicking on it brings me to the permission management dialog.

I would prefer if it wouldn't always clog up space in the notifications. Is there a way to hide it without changing to automatically allowing all permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Longpress on notification than tap on 'i' and check block all notifications, but beaware if is permission management part of system you will maybe not be allowed to block notifications or it will block notifications that you don't want to block.

Comment: Unfortunately the "block all" choice isn't offered. Do you know whether this behavior is special to vernee or whether it's default for Android 6.0?

Comment: Yeah, i tought so. I'm not sure, some time ago I had same problem on SlimKat ROM where I couldn't hide that notification when permission manager is runing. There was some xposed module which allows blocking certain notifications but I can't remeber it's name. But now on stock marshmallow I dont get that notifications ever.